# Extracting data from nested dictionary, TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm receiving the following error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

when I'm trying to print some data that is within a nested dictionary

```
{u'id': u'000123', u'payload': u"{'account_title': u’sam b’, 'phone_num': ‘1234567890’, 'security_pin': u'000000', 'remote_word': u’secret123’, 'email_address': ‘email@gmail.com’, 'password': u’password123’}”}
```

For example, let's say the above was assigned to the variable 'account_info'

`print(account_info['payload'])` <- will print everything from 'payload' onwards

but when I use:

```
print(account_info['payload']['email_address'])
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `payload`'s value is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: How would I refer to email_address so I could assign a variable to it's value?

Comment: take out the '' in the dict after payload (and also at the end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `payload` value is a string, you need to convert it to dict before indexing. There are [few ways of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/988228/728795), here is one with eval:

```
import ast
...
payload = ast.literal_eval(account_info['payload'])
print(payload['email_address'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `payload`'s value is a string, not a dictionary, it cannot be indexed as such. Remove the quotes around the nested dictionary for the code to work:

```
account_info = {u'id': u'000123', u'payload': {'account_title': u'sam b', 'phone_num': '1234567890', 'security_pin': u'000000', 'remote_word': u'secret123', 'email_address': 'email@gmail.com', 'password': u'password123'}}

print(account_info["payload"]["email_address"])
```

Answer (score 0):

`account_info['payload']` is a string with `bad single quotes`, so you should remove all bad single quotes with the replace method and convert the string into a dictionary using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). without removing bad single quotes `ast.literal_eval()` method will raise `SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier error`.

**Ex.**

```
import ast
account_info = {u'id': u'000123', u'payload': u"{'account_title': u’sam b’, 'phone_num': ‘1234567890’,"
                               u" 'security_pin': u'000000', 'remote_word': u’secret123’, "
                               u"'email_address': ‘email@gmail.com’, 'password': u’password123’}"}

account_info['payload'] = ast.literal_eval(account_info['payload'].replace("‘","'").replace("’","'"))
print(account_info['payload']['email_address'])
```

**O/P:**

```
email@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined it the value of `account_info['payload']` is a string object that looks like a dictionary. Define it like this instead:

```
account_info = {u'id': u'000123', u'payload': {u'account_title': u’sam b’, u'phone_num': ‘1234567890’, u'security_pin': u'000000', u'remote_word': u’secret123’, u'email_address': u‘email@gmail.com’, u'password': u’password123’}}
```

With this definition the value of `account_info['payload']` is now a dictionary and `account_info['payload']['email_address']` will return 'email@gmail.com'